# Customize non form errors with django crispy form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-crispy-forms

I would like to customize the way django crispy shows the non form error. I know how to change the text, but I don't know where to change the css.

This is the image:
[My login area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zFe3.png)

forms.py

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    alphanumeric = RegexValidator(r'^[0-9a-zA-Z]*$', 'Only alphanumeric characters are allowed.')
    username = forms.CharField(label='', required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Username'}))
    password = forms.CharField(label='', required=True, widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Password'}))
    name = forms.CharField(label='', 
                        required=True ,  
                        validators=[alphanumeric], 
                        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Name'}))


    def clean(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data.get('username')
        password = self.cleaned_data.get('password')
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if not user or not user.is_active:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Invalid Login : I want to change this CSS')
        return self.cleaned_data

    def login(self, request):
        username = self.cleaned_data.get('username')
        password = self.cleaned_data.get('password')
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        return user
```

template - html

```
<form method="POST" action="">{% csrf_token %}
    <!--{% if  form.non_field_errors %}
        testing
    {% endif %}-->
    {{form|crispy}}
    <div class="form-info">
        <label class="hvr-sweep-to-right">
            <input class="create btn"  type="submit" value="Submit">
        </label>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you use your crispy forms with bootstrap (depending on the style from the image).

So you can just **overwrite** the original bootstrap classes

```
.alert {
  padding: 0.75rem 1.25rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
}

.alert-danger {
  background-color: #f2dede;
  border-color: #ebcccc;
  color: #a94442;
}

.alert-danger hr {
  border-top-color: #e4b9b9;
}

.alert-danger .alert-link {
  color: #843534;
}
```

or other alert classes e.g. alert-success.

If you don't want to overwrite these classes for the whole project just set a div around your crispy forms

```
<div class"crispyform">
  {{form|crispy}}
</div>
```

and write in your custom css s.th. like

```
.crispyform .alert {
  # your new style
}
```

Comment: Thks bro! I've been studying the backend,  now it is time to go for the frontend. I was trying to send the error as django.message then I would customize it. But your way is simpliest!